# The package rxjs does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, rxjs

Upon doing `npm install`, I encountered the error:

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.10.1
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package rxjs does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.4 wants rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer angular2@2.0.0-beta.15 wants rxjs@5.0.0-beta.2
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/router@3.0.0-beta.2 wants rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/http@2.0.0-rc.4 wants rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     c:\GIT\mas\Rapid\factory\npm-debug.log
```

Here's the `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "sdk",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "typings install && bower install --production && jspm install && node src/tools/updateDependencies.js && npm run bundle-dep",
    "_jspm": "jspm install",
    "_postjspm": "node src/tools/updateDependencies.js && npm run bundle-dep",
    "bundle-dep": "jspm bundle \"src - [src/**/*] - [components/**/*]\" www/bundle.js",
    "start": "node dev-server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.2",
    "bower": "^1.7.9",
    "chokidar-socket-emitter": "^0.3.1",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "jspm": "^0.17.0-beta.12",
    "open": "0.0.5",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "spdy": "^3.2.3",
    "typings": "^0.7.12"
  },
  "jspm": {
    "name": "sdk",
    "directories": {
      "lib": "src"
    },
    "dependencies": {
      "@angular/forms": "npm:@angular/forms@^0.2.0",
      "@angular/http": "npm:@angular/http@^2.0.0-rc.4",
      "@angular/router": "npm:@angular/router@^3.0.0-beta.2",
      "core-js": "npm:core-js@^2.4.1",
      "es6-shim": "github:es-shims/es6-shim@^0.35.0",
      "json": "github:systemjs/plugin-json@^0.1.0",
      "systemjs-hot-reloader": "github:capaj/systemjs-hot-reloader@^0.5.6"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "os": "github:jspm/nodelibs-os@^0.2.0-alpha",
      "plugin-typescript": "github:frankwallis/plugin-typescript@^4.0.5"
    },
    "peerDependencies": {
      "@angular/common": "npm:@angular/common@^2.0.0-rc.4",
      "@angular/compiler": "npm:@angular/compiler@^2.0.0-rc.4",
      "@angular/core": "npm:@angular/core@^2.0.0-rc.4",
      "@angular/platform-browser": "npm:@angular/platform-browser@^2.0.0-rc.4",
      "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic@^2.0.0-rc.4",
      "assert": "github:jspm/nodelibs-assert@^0.2.0-alpha",
      "fs": "github:jspm/nodelibs-fs@^0.2.0-alpha",
      "net": "github:jspm/nodelibs-net@^0.2.0-alpha",
      "path": "github:jspm/nodelibs-path@^0.2.0-alpha",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@^0.2.0-alpha",
      "reflect-metadata": "npm:reflect-metadata@0.1.2",
      "rxjs": "npm:rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6",
      "tty": "github:jspm/nodelibs-tty@^0.2.0-alpha",
      "util": "github:jspm/nodelibs-util@^0.2.0-alpha",
      "zone.js": "npm:zone.js@^0.6.6"
    },
    "overrides": {
      "npm:@angular/common@2.0.0-rc.4": {
        "meta": {
          "src/*.js": {
            "deps": [
              "reflect-metadata",
              "zone.js"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "npm:@angular/compiler@2.0.0-rc.4": {
        "meta": {
          "src/*.js": {
            "deps": [
              "reflect-metadata",
              "zone.js"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "npm:@angular/core@2.0.0-rc.4": {
        "meta": {
          "src/*.js": {
            "deps": [
              "reflect-metadata",
              "zone.js"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "npm:@angular/http@2.0.0-rc.4": {
        "meta": {
          "src/*.js": {
            "deps": [
              "reflect-metadata",
              "zone.js"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.0.0-rc.4": {
        "meta": {
          "src/*.js": {
            "deps": [
              "reflect-metadata",
              "zone.js"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "npm:@angular/platform-browser@2.0.0-rc.4": {
        "meta": {
          "src/*.js": {
            "deps": [
              "reflect-metadata",
              "zone.js"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "npm:debug@2.2.0": {
        "main": "browser.js",
        "jspmNodeConversion": false,
        "format": "cjs",
        "map": {
          "./browser.js": {
            "node": "./node.js"
          },
          "fs": "@node/fs",
          "net": "@node/net",
          "tty": "@node/tty",
          "util": "@node/util"
        }
      },
      "npm:ms@0.7.1": {
        "jspmNodeConversion": false,
        "format": "cjs"
      },
      "npm:reflect-metadata@0.1.2": {
        "map": {
          "crypto": "@empty"
        }
      },
      "npm:typescript@1.8.9": {
        "browser": {},
        "map": {
          "buffer": "@empty",
          "child_process": "@empty",
          "fs": "@empty",
          "path": "@empty",
          "process": "@empty",
          "readline": "@empty"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried upgrading `"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2"` to `"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6"` under `devDependencies`, but it gave me:

```
npm ERR! peerinvalid The package rxjs does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer angular2@2.0.0-beta.15 wants rxjs@5.0.0-beta.2
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.4 wants rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/http@2.0.0-rc.4 wants rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/router@3.0.0-beta.2 wants rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are actually two versions of Angular 2 installed in this project. Old (`angular2`) and new (`@angular`).
So I uninstalled the old one by this command:

```
npm uninstall angular2
```

then retried:

```
npm install
```

then:

```
npm start
```